# Is it possible to grant a Bigquery authorized view without anything else using only one dataset

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

In [this](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/authorized-views#go) they seem to be using a separate datasets for the views and underlying tables. And granting the whole views dataset to grantee.

Is it necessary to use separate datasets provided I'll only grant `BigQuery Data Viewer` on the view instead?

Answer (score 0):

For authorized views, there are 2 levels :

- table or view
- dataset

Example with `dataset` level :

```
- private_dataset
   table1
   table2
   
- public_dataset
  view1 => authorized view on the entire private_dataset
  view2 => authorized view on the entire private_dataset
```

Example with `table` level :

```
- private_dataset
   table1
   table2
   
- public_dataset
  view1 => authorized view on the table1 in private_dataset
  view2 => authorized view on the table2 in private_dataset
```

[authorized view BigQuery](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/share-access-views)

In the previous examples, a new dataset `public_dataset` is created to expose views to partnairs. Views apply the needed filters to control rows exposed to partnairs.

Then you can create a `Google Group` containing a set of identities and give a role `BigQuery Data Viewer` on the `public_dataset`.

Example : `Google Group` `my_partnair@googlegroups.com` is `Bigquery Data Viewer` on dataset `public_dataset`

For the decision between `dataset` and `table` level, it depends on you and your use case.

Answer (score 0):

Authorized view in BigQuery are used to share the query results with the users and groups where they do not have access to the underlying source data.  For implementing this principal, you need to create a new separate dataset which is used to store the authorized view that you share with other users. In this way the accounts will not be able to view the underlying source dataset.

For authorized view, a separate dataset needs to be created as mentioned in this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/share-access-views#create_a_dataset_where_you_can_store_your_view). Then the owners can grant access to the authorized view without giving them access to the underlying source dataset.

If you want the users or groups to run jobs including query job then you can grant `bigquery.user` role at project level and for querying the view they need to be given `bigquery.dataViewer` role on the dataset containing the view. For more information you can check this [link](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/share-access-views#assign_access_controls_to_the_dataset_containing_the_view).